# Targeting nested tables

Tags: css

I have a table inside of a table, a really simple one.
What I wanted to do is to avoid having `border-bottom` of `td` tag in the last row (`tr`) of the table. What I did is this:

```
tbody tr:last-of-type td { border-bottom: none; }
```

I was thinking that this is it, but then I checked the last row of not nested table and the whole nested table was not having a bottom border. Is there a way to avoid this using simple CSS without classes etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve *no border bottom* of the *nested table*, you can do so like so:

```
tbody table td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

**Note** - *the above rule makes assumptions about your CSS, which you haven't shared with us*.  Due to you not including the CSS that applies the border in the first place, it is possible the above won't work due to [CSS specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

For example, if your rule that adds border to the table is:

```
tbody tr td {
    border-bottom: [whatever style];
}
```

Then, the selector you need to use to remove the nested table border is:

```
tbody tr table td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Add your CSS, and we can more accurately answer your question.  Or, better yet - read the [CSS specificity article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), and you'll know how to alter the selector yourself!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the simplest way is to use class and id. Like so:

```
table.outer { some: style; } /* class */  
table#inner { some: style; } /* id */
```

But as you said, AVOID classes, then perhaps call the table nested within the table like so:

```
table { some: style; }  
table table { some: style; } /* override outer table */
```